# Inconsistency in full text search in mysql 5.7

Tags: mysql, full-text-indexing

I am trying to use Full Text Search. I enabled full text search on 'F_400011_0' column of my table.

When I try to search using 'sjc' pattern, I am getting the desired result.

```
mysql> SELECT F_400011_0 FROM D_resource_88217d81_1afa_4721_abad_c97154ce2987 t0 
    -> WHERE t0.tenant_id = 'client_5' AND ( MATCH (t0.F_400011_0) AGAINST ('sjc' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)) limit 5;
+----------------------+
| F_400011_0           |
+----------------------+
| vmysql02-sjc         |
| vJobProcessor162-sjc |
| pkafka23-sjc         |
| vmysql66-sjc         |
| pkafka119-sjc        |
+----------------------+
5 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

When I try to search using '**vapp**' pattern, I am not getting the desired result.

```
mysql> SELECT F_400011_0 FROM D_resource_88217d81_1afa_4721_abad_c97154ce2987 t0 
    -> WHERE t0.tenant_id = 'client_5' AND ( MATCH (t0.F_400011_0) AGAINST ('vapp' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)) limit 5;

Empty set (0.12 sec)
```

But in actual we do have records with 'vapp' pattern. Please look at the results of the following LIKE query on the same 'vapp' pattern.

```
mysql> SELECT F_400011_0 FROM D_resource_88217d81_1afa_4721_abad_c97154ce2987 t0 
    -> WHERE t0.tenant_id = 'client_5' AND t0.F_400011_0 LIKE 'vapp%' limit 5;
+-------------+
| F_400011_0  |
+-------------+
| vapp148-sjc |
| vapp210-rc  |
| vapp99-sjc  |
| vapp131-sjc |
| vapp249-sjc |
+-------------+
```

Environment:
**MySQL Version:** *mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.26, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper*

**OS Version:** 
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic

Comment: How many rows *don't* match the criteria?

Comment: What is the minimum token size in your full-text index?

Comment: approximately 1000 rows dont match the criteria whats the relation again @Strawberry

Comment: the minimum token size is 3 in any way the sjc also has 3 tokens @Barmar

Comment: Long story short, if you need exact results for a specific phrase add another condition using “like” and combine both with OR

Comment: @emix thats not our use case.

Comment: So have you read how fulltext search works? It doesn't work like LIKE, don't expect same results. It's a natural fulltext search. It won't work well with such short inputs like `vapp`.